# Regular Expressions to fix invalid HTML

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-2012

I have hundreds of files (ancient ASP and HTML) filled with outdated and often completely invalid HTML code.

Between Visual Studio and ReSharper, this invalid HTML is flagged and easily visible if the editor window is scrolled to where the invalid HTML appears. However, neither tool is providing any method to quickly fix the errors across the whole project.

The first few errors on which ReSharper focuses my attention are tags that are either not closed or closed but not opened. Sometimes this occurs because the opening and closing tags overlap - for instance:

```xml
<font face=verdana size=5><b>some text</font></b>

<span><p>start of a paragraph
    with multiple lines of <i><b>text/hmtl
    </i> with a nice mix of junk</b>
</span></p>
```

Sometimes opening tags without a corresponding closing tag were allowed in older versions of HTML (or the tools which generated the HTML didn't care about the standards as some browsers *usually* figured out what the author meant). So the mess I'm attempting to clean up has many unclosed HTML tags that ought to be closed.

```xml
<font face = tahoma size=2>some more text<b><sup>*</sup></b>
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

And just for good measure, the code includes lots of closing HTML tags that have no matching start tag.

```xml
</b><p>some text that is actually within closed tags</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So, other than writing a new application to parse, flag, and fix all these errors - does anyone have some .Net regular expressions that could be used to locate and preferably fix this stuff with Visual Studio 2012's Search and Replace feature?

Though a single expression that does it all would be nice, multiple expressions that each handle one of the above cases would still be very helpful.

For the case of overlapped HTML tags, I'm using this expression:

```
(?n)(?<t1s>(?><(?<t1>\w+)[^>]*>))(?<c1>((?!</\k<t1>>)(\n|.))*?)(?<t2s>(?><(?!\k<t1>)(?<t2>(?>\w+))[^>]*>))(?<c2>((?!(</(\k<t1>|\k<t2>)>))(\n|.))*?)(?<t1e></\k<t1>>)(?<c3>(?>(\n|.)*?))(?<t2e></\k<t2>>)

Explanation:
    (?n) Ignore unnamed captures.
    (?<t1s>(?><(?<t1>\w+)[^>]*>)) Get the first tag, capturing the full tag and attributes
      for replacement and the name alone for further matching.
    (?<c1>((?!</\k<t1>>)(\n|.))*?) Capture content between the first and second tag.
    (?<t2s>(?><(?!\k<t1>)(?<t2>(?>\w+))[^>]*>)) Get the 2nd tag, capturing the full
      tag and attributes for replacement, the name along for further matching, and ensuring
      it does not match the 1st tag and that the first tag is still open.
    (?<c2>((?!(</(\k<t1>|\k<t2>)>))(\n|.))*?) Capture content between the second tag 
      closing of the first tag.
    (?<t1e></\k<t1>>) Capture the closing of the first tag, where the second tag is
      still open.
    (?<c3>(?>(\n|.)*?)) Capture content between the closing of the first tag and the closing
      of the second tag.
    (?<t2e></\k<t2>>) Capture the closing of the second tag.
```

With this replacement expression:

```
${t1s}${c1}${t2s}${c2}${t2e}${c3}${t1e}
```

The issues with this search expression is that it is painfully slow. Using `.` instead of `(\n|.)` for the three content captures is much quicker, but limits the results to just those where the overlapped tags and intervening content are on a single line.

The expression will also match valid, properly closed and properly nested HTML if the first tag appears inside the content of the second tag, like this:

```xml
<font color=green><b>hello world</b></font><span class="whatever"><font color=red>*</font></span>
```

So it is not safe to use the expression in a "Replace All" operation, especially across the hundreds of files in the solution.

For unclosed tags, I've successfully handled the self-closing tags: `<img/>`, `<meta/>`, `<input/>`, `<link/>`, `<br/>`, and `<hr/>`. However, I've still not attempted the generic case for all the other tags - those that may have content or should be closed with a separate closing tag.

Also, I've no idea how to match closing tags without a matching opening tag. The simple solution of `</\w+>` will match all closing tags regardless of whether or not they have a matched opening tag.

Comment: there are some tools specifically designed to handle "tag soup" - like [HTML agility pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). You would have to create some code to point it to all relevant files, but it may help you :) anyway, just a thought

Comment: Isn't *invalid* HTML context sensitive?

Comment: @Laurel - yes, though I'm attempting to update this mess to something abiding by the latest HTML standards rather than the loose stuff IE has accepted in the past.

Comment: My point is: Regexes are level 3 Chomsky, and context-sensitive HTML is level 1. People get upset when you "parse" with Regexes, and that's only level 2.

Comment: Well, there's one thing I can help you with: add the Singleline option - `(?s)` - to make the dot to match newlines.  Beyond that, Balancing Groups will get probably get you further toward your goal. but not all the way.  We don't need Chomsky to tell us tag soup is a bitch to work with. ;)

Comment: @AlanMoore I tried the `(?s)` option, but it did not have the desired effect. I still had to use `(\n|.)` to match form feed characters along with everything else. I'm wondering if Visual Studio overrides some of the inline regex options... or if my regex was too complicated...

Answer (score 1):

According to their website, Resharper has this feature:

## Solution-Wide Analysis

> Not only is ReSharper capable of analyzing a specific code file for errors, but it can extend its analysis skills to cover your whole solution.

...

> All you have to do is explicitly switch Solution-Wide Analysis on, and then, after it analyzes the code of your solution, view the list of errors in a dedicated window:

[[image: Many errors here]]

> Even without opening that window, you can still easily navigate through errors in your solution with Go to Next Error in Solution (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>) and Go to Previous Error in Solution (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) commands.

## Your current "solution" is to use regexes on a *context-sensitive* language (invalid HTML). Please, NO. People flip out already when people suggest parsing *context-free* languages with regexes.

On second thought, there might be a solution that we can use regexes for.

For this HTML:

```
<i><b>text/html
</i> with a nice mix of junk</b>
```

A better transformation would be (it's more valid, right?):

```
<i><\i><b><i>text/hmtl
</i> with a nice mix of junk</b>
```

There are many ways this could go wrong, (although it's pretty bad as-is), but I assume you have this all backed up. This regex (where `i` is an example of a tag you may want to do this with):

```
<(i(?: [^>]+)?)>([^<]*)<(\/?[^i](?: [^>]+)?)>
```

Might help you out. I don't know how regex replace works in whatever flavor you're using, but if you replace $0 (everything matched by the regex) with `<$1>$2</$1><$3><$1>`, you'll get the transformation I'm talking about.

Comment: For some reason, ReSharper 8's feature set is a bit limited with classic ASP... Many of the features I find useful with C# are grayed out or otherwise unavailable. For instance, the useful suggestions when I bring up ReSharper's context menu on a flagged error may have the option to remove the offending tag, but often all it has is the choice to ignore the errors.

Comment: Still, the suggestion to review ReSharper's feature *is* useful, as I was having difficulty find the ReSharper error list and now I've got it in front of me - which speeds up my work.

Comment: Well, that error window enabled me to quickly fix some JavaScript and CSS in the project, but still have some large files with nasty messes of HTML.

Comment: @Zarepheth I added one regex for you to try. Be careful.

Comment: Thanks! My current replacement expressions was simply swapping the two closing tags - which might change the browser's behavior. Your solution of terminating the first just before and opening a new one just after the second tag is probably better. By the way, I'm using .Net RegEx's: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx